# Remove currency from price in twig templates

Tags: replace, preg-replace, number-formatting

I need to remove currency symbol from amount. 
If currency symbol are in left like `$20.00` working this:
  `order.total|replace('/[^0-9+]/', '')` 
but if currency symbol in right side for example `20.00€` - does not work.

Can anybody help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove any non-digit chars at the start and end of the string use

```
replace('/^\D+|\D+$/', '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GUaZ74/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of the string followd with...
- `\D+` - 1+ chars other than a digit
- `|` - or
- `\D+$` - 1+ chars other than a digit at the end of the string.